# How to show current location of multiple users on webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps, geolocation

I am working on a website whose requirement is to show current locations of multiple users on PC.
The location needs to be show on PC website and Users location needs to be fetched from their GPS enabled mobile (Android or Iphone).
Is there any way that I can see current position of particular mobile device(android or iphone) on my PC webapge?
Please , help me to achieve it using JS

Answer (score 0):

simply make them to sign into the account, and have some kind of user id. Then have a logic which with the user can upload & update the location in your site, save the location with id (alongside time stamp) in a database, And then create a map, and load the data from database and show different users in the map.

Then decide whether the timestamps information could be used to disqualify the location, and how often you want to refresh the map.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But, actually I have to show something like navigator .I have to monitor the users on the map like where are they going , their each movement...

Comment: then you would only need to store multiple locations. the timestamp then could indicate which order you create the routepoints

Comment: No, I have to implement something like GPS navigator, a webpage in which all users should be visible with their current location (their moving position)